# How to create a heatmap kind of visulalization for data

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have pandas dataframe that has the following structure

| BID | EID |
| --- | --- |
| B1 | 1001,1002 |
| B2 | 1001,1003,1006 |
| B3 | 1004,1006,1008,1005 |
| B4 | 1001,1002,1003,10004,1005,1008 |

I want to report the COUNT of how many common EIDs are there amongst the BIDs.
I want visualization in the following format

|  | B1 | B2 | B3 | B4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| B1 | n/a | 1 | 0 | 2 |
| B2 | 1 | n/a | 2 | 3 |
| B3 | 0 | 2 | n/a | 4 |
| B4 | 2 | 3 | 4 | n/a |

How can i achieve this ? Also higher the number in the cell, i want to highlight dark as it appears in heat map. Appreciate your help.

My logic is ..
Create a pandas dataframe with BID as index
Loop through each BID and compare it with other BIDs
Create a new column
Each of new column will be a list (This list will contain the count of EIDs)
How to Convert this dataframe to heat map ?

or any easy logic that I can implement ?

Comment: What have you tried, why did it fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I'm new here but here is my solution :)

first of all for each BID create a column with his data.

```
tmp = df["EID"].apply(pd.Series).set_index(df["BID"].values).T
```

next build the structure of the correlation with corr()

```
corr_df=tmp.corr()
```

Then change the values of the corr

```
import itertools
for a, b in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(tmp.columns, 2,): 
  corr_df.loc[[a],[b]]=len(set(tmp[a]) & set(tmp[b])) # len of equal items
  corr_df.loc[[b],[a]]=len(set(tmp[a]) & set(tmp[b]))
  corr_df.loc[[a],[a]]=np.NAN
print(corr_df)
```

output:

```
          B1   B2   B3   B4
     B1  NaN  1.0  0.0  2.0
     B2  1.0  NaN  1.0  2.0
     B3  0.0  1.0  NaN  3.0
     B4  2.0  2.0  3.0  NaN
```

heatmap code:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go # for visualization

fig = go.Figure(data=go.Heatmap(
                   z=corr_df,
                   x=corr_df.columns,
                   y=corr_df.columns,
                   hoverongaps = False,
                   colorscale="Greys",))
fig.update_layout(
    title="HeatMap",
    width=600
)
fig.show()
```

output:

[image]

Comment: Hello Aviv, I am getting error on itertools for loop.

KeyError : "None of [Index(['BID1], dtype='object')] are in the [index]

Comment: @user18205266 first sorry for the delay I was in vacation :) 
second I don't know why you have the error code. do you use the same columns names in the df?